# UICollectionView : Programmatically moving focus from one view to another - tvOS

Tags: swift2, tvos

I am trying to move focus programmatically from one view to another like on a button click i am trying to select an Index in collection View.

I am trying to replicate the working functionality as SIRI as siri is not open for developers yet i am sending the show to be played via bonjour to the app so that it plays it only point is that the show i.e index path should be focussed before the videos is played Like NBC app does in tvOS.

I tried:

```
- collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
       collectionView.reloadData()
       setNeedsFocusUpdate()
       collectionView.updateFocusIfNeeded()
```

nothing seems to be working and moving the focus to given Index i wonder is that possible in tvOS or not?

I am building an tvOS native application.

Comment: Does the collection view already have focus? Or are you asking how to move focus from another control to (an item in) the collection view?

Comment: PetahChristian - I am on a button say search i clicked that button or if i am another control and i want to move the the focus to a collectionView item to a particular index  on that button click.Moving focus from current control to another.                                                                                           Functionality i am trying to achieve is that when i get a text through bluetooth/iPhone Device i need to focus that particular show in the collectionView and play that show

Comment: As the first part of the answer mentions, it's not explicitly possible to programmatically move focus from a button to a collection view.  You can try to game the focus engine into doing something it doesn't permit, by conditionally changing the view controller's `preferredFocusedView`, but it really violates the human interface guidelines, as well as creates an inconsistent, confusing, and possibly frustrating user experience.

Answer (score 11):

There's no explicit way to programmatically move focus from one view to another, per the [App Programming Guide for tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html):

> **The Focus Engine Controls Focus**
>
> Only the focus engine can explicitly update focus, meaning there is no API for directly setting the focused view or moving focus in a certain direction. ...
>
> The focus engine controls focus to make sure that it does not move around the screen unexpectedly, and that it behaves similarly across different applications.

However, you can have your [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView:) specify an index path for your collection view's preferred focus item, which will focus that index path when the collection view is focused:

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    // Return index path for selected show that you will be playing
    return NSIndexPath(forRow: ..., inSection: ...)
}
```

> The functionality of this delegate method is equivalent to overriding the UICollectionView class’s preferredFocusedView method in the UIFocusEnvironment protocol. If the collection view’s remembersLastFocusedIndexPath method is set to YES, this method defines the index path that gets focused when the collection view is focused for the first time.

Comment: -Thanks for reply PC. Well i was expecting the samething. Well if you see NBC or NetFlix apps they move the focus when we give name of the show from SIRI. How do that work? Do you have any idea or have you seen this behaviour in your apps?

Comment: @iWorld Did you implement `indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView` to return the index path for the item you want to select, before you programmatically select that item?

Comment: Yes i did implement that.                                                                    Action :
    let index = NSIndexPath(forItem: 2, inSection: 0)
    self.collectionView1.selectItemAtIndexPath(index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
    self.collectionView1.reloadData()
    self.collectionView1.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
    self.collectionView1.updateFocusIfNeeded()
  }
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if collectionView == self.collectionView1{
      return NSIndexPath(forItem: 2, inSection: 0)
    }
  }

Comment: @iWorld Since the collection view doesn't have focus, it's not going to ask its delegate which item should be focused.